# XLib XGetImage is very slow

Tags: performance, user-interface, graphics, xlib

XGetImage function takes approximately 1.7 seconds.  I need to use XGetImage to record the display screen 3 times per second. I don't believe XShmGetImage is available.  I am calling XGetImage from a library file.

Any idea why it would be this slow??  If XGetImage took 100 milli-seconds I would be fine.

I have a feeling that I am either using a package or missing a package which is causing this extremely poor performance.  Even when using the GUI for firefox or a GNOME terminal, the graphics seems to display slow.

I am using SLES 11.3 64bit on an IBM server.  Matrox G200 EV graphics card.  LEN Lenovo LEN L1900PA display with 1280x1024 resolution and 16.7 Mio. (24 bit color).  Loads of RAM.  Intel Xeon E5620 8 core processor 2.4 GHz.  Nothing else running on the machine.

Again any suggestions of why XGetImage is slow?

Comment: You have a 1998-era card. And you are running graphic tasks with it. On a server. Why? Anyway, check which driver your X server is using (look in `/var/log/Xorg*log`).

Comment: I am using XGetImage function that performs GUI automation testing of simple programs we ship.  Basically, just taking screenshots at regular intervals to make sure the product GUI program is at an expected state.  This is a test machine to make sure our product works on IBM servers.

Comment: You don't need a graphic card for that. Run Xvfb.

Comment: Running Xvfb says the following

Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
 If this is no longer urnning remove /tmp/.X0-lock
 and start again.

Comment: (II) Module mga: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.4.11
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 5.0

Comment: You need to run Xvfb on a screen which is not 0, because 0 is taken by your other X server (which you should not be running on a server).

Comment: I'm going to have to run Xvfb later.  I will post again when I can.

Comment: XShmGetImage may be faster!?